# transfer localhost web directory to github repository

Tags: git, repository, push, pull

I created an account at github.com and im very new to git. I have ubuntu and have a web folder in htdocs. I want to be able to commit any changes and show up in github repository which i created. When i try

```
 git commit {github url}
```

it does not show up on the github website. I know i first need to push the folder to git but when i try to push nothing happens.

I followed some tutorial to set up the git on my computer and i think it worked since it created .git folder.

Any help would be appreciated or a link to a good git/github configuration tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already created an empty repository on github, you need to use `git push origin` to push your commits to github *after* you added github as `origin`:

```
git add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

You can also check the `remote`s you have by:

```
git remote -v
```

More for your eference: [Adding a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote)

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a URL when committing, it's a local operation. You commit your changes, and then you push them to your Github repository.

All the information you need on getting started with a new Github repository is here: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo.